# Problems with a series and a wrong problem statement suspected

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

I've been fighting with the following task:
The series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ is convergent in the points $a$ and $b$, and the functions $f_n(x)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, are monotonic over the interval $[a, b]$. I have to proove that the series is absolutely and uniformly convergent over $[a, b]$.

The problem is that I could easily proove it if the series was absolutely convergent in $a$ and $b$, but since it's only convergent, I don't know what to do, cause everything I tried met with complete failure. I start to think that it might be a mistake of the teacher, who has forgotten the word "absolutely" in the beginning of the task.

Without that word I can't find a sequence $c_n \geq |f_n(x)|$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and I can't use the principle of Weierstrass.

If someone could give me at least a guideline, I would be very grateful. 
And sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That statement seems to be wrong. As a counter-example, take the (constant) functions $f_n(x) = y_n $ where $(y_n)$ is any sequence such that 
$\sum y_n$ is convergent but not absolutely convergent.